# Fluorescent fitting problem

Tags: lighting, light, fluorescent

I live in France.
I have just received a replacement twin fluorescent fitting to replace a unit that failed after 3 months. I have tested the new fitting on a bench, connecting live neutral and earth via a wall socket and it works fine.
As soon as I connect it to the live, neutral and earth on the ceiling, i get a flicker from one tube then nothing. 
If I connect a lamp holder the 60w bulb works fine. I have replaced both (two way) switches with the same outcome. Other lights on the lighting circuit work perfectly. 
Does anyone have any suggestions where to look next. The 60w bulb is hopelessly inadequate for my workshop space.

Comment: Are your switches standard snap switches? Some electronic ballasts do not work with electronic switches or dimmers.

Comment: Is the earthing good at the lamp location? Will the unit work on the bench without an earth? Warning/avis, this could result in the metal chassis of the fixture becoming energized at 230V!!